Estou com um problema no meu script SQL na hora de dar insert , Sou iniciante e preciso de ajuda
Boa tarde, estou com um projeto para ser entregue no curso e fiquei estagnado por causa de um ERRO no meu script
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`osoficina`.`problemidentification`, CONSTRAINT `fk_problemIdt_teamCons` FOREIGN KEY (`idTeamConsOs`) REFERENCES `teamconserto` (`idTeamConserto`))

    create table clients(  
       idClient int auto_increment primary key,
       idOSconserto int,
       idOSrev int,
       carModel varchar(100) not null,
       nomeClient varchar(100) not null,
       CPF char(11) not null,
       constraint unique_cpf_client unique (CPF)
);
       alter table clients auto_increment=1;

        create table systema( 
        idSystema int auto_increment primary key,
        idClientSystema int,
        consertoType varchar(255) not null,
        revisão varchar(100) not null,
        constraint fk_systema_clients foreign key (idClientSystema) references clients(idClient)
    
);
alter table systema auto_increment=1;

        create table teamConserto (
        idTeamConserto int auto_increment primary key,
        idTeamConsOs int,
        nomeEmploye varchar(100) not null,
        registrationWork char(4) not null,
        especialidade varchar(100) not null,
        address varchar(100)
);

alter table teamConserto auto_increment=1;


        create table teamRevisão (
        idTeamRevisão int auto_increment primary key,
        nomeEmploye varchar(100) not null,
        registrationWork char(4) not null,
        especialidade varchar(100) not null,
        address varchar(100)
);

alter table teamRevisão auto_increment=1;

            create table problemIdentification (
            idSystemaOs int,
            idTeamConsOs int default 1,
            primary key (idSystemaOs, idTeamConsOs),
            problemaRelatado varchar(200) not null,
            constraint fk_problemIdt_systema foreign key (idSystemaOs) references systema(idSystema),
            constraint fk_problemIdt_teamCons foreign key (idteamConsOs) references teamConserto(idTeamConserto)

);


            create table revisão (
            idSystemaRev int,
            idTeamRev int,
            revisãoOk bool default true,
            primary key (idSystemaRev, idTeamRev),
            constraint fk_revisão_systema foreign key (idSystemaRev) references systema(idSystema),
            constraint fk_revisão_TeamRev foreign key (idTeamRev) references teamRevisão(idTeamRevisão)
);

             create table consertoOS (
             idConsertoOS int auto_increment primary key,
             idTeamConsOS int,
             valorPecas float not null,
             dataEntrega varchar(15),
             pagamento enum ('Cartão debito', 'Cartão credito', 'Dinheiro', 'Pix') not null,
             cancelamento enum ('Sim', 'Não') not null,
            constraint fk_consertoOS_teamCons foreign key (idTeamConsOS) references teamConserto(idTeamConserto)
);
alter table consertoOS auto_increment=1;

             create table revisãoOS (
             idRevisãoOS int auto_increment primary key,
             idTeamRevOS int,
             valorPecas float not null,
             dataEntrega varchar(15),
             pagamento enum ('Cartão debito', 'Cartão credito', 'Dinheiro', 'Pix') not null,
             cancelamento enum ('Sim', 'Não') not null,
             constraint fk_revisãoOS_teamRev foreign key (idTeamRevOS) references teamRevisão(idTeamRevisão)
);
alter table revisãoOS auto_increment=1;
alter table clients add constraint fk_osConserto_client foreign key (idOSconserto) references consertoOS (idConsertoOS);
alter table clients add constraint fk_osRev_client foreign key (idOSrev) references revisãoOS (idRevisãoOS);

A tabela que esta dando erro é a problemIdentification, não sei mais o que fazer.

Você perguntou isso aqui já: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/596584/5878

Sim, mas não consegui entender sua resposta.

Não duplique publicações, faça as correções na publicação original. Não faça saudações, cumprimentos ou agradecimentos nas publicações. Seja objetivo e forneça um [mcve] que permita o leitor replicar no ambiente dele exatamente o mesmo problema relatado na pergunta. Veja [ask] e leia com atenção as orientações e links da [help].
